# Copy emails in Outlook Express

Tags: email, outlook

A friend of mine wants to share around 100 e-mails with me. We both use Outook express 6.0 I have asked him to copy the e-mails in a separate folder and then send the .dbx file for that folder to me.

Pls let me know if this is the right way and how do I go about importing the e-mails from .dbx file into my Outlook Express.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use an IMAP server with a shared folder. Generally [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) is considered state of the art these days for small installation. If you need to go really large you might want to look into [cyrus](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/) and [cyrus-murder](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/imapd/install-murder.html).

On a sidenote: OX is usually one of the worst mail clients to use from a server point of view. If you are only trying to share mails, simply wait for [superuser.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/) to launch, this is intended for power users and not system administrators.

Comment: See, basically we are two totally different networks so we cannot have shared folder.

Comment: It doesn't matter on which network you are with an IMAP server. Just grab a server box and set up an IMAP server.

Answer (score 1):

Can the emails not just be drag&dropped to a folder as .EML files?

Answer (score 1):

When You receive .dbx file You can do a trick,
Firs Make Folder in application with same name as it was at your freind and as is name of file
After that exit from outlook and overwrite file created by outlook with file from your firend

To find  location of existing dbx files go to tools/options tab maintenance and button "store folder" Then copy the given path to address bar into windows explorer